# Can I use a Soft body / cloth simulation to make a realistic cushion?

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

I am trying to make a leather cushion look more realistic by simulation. 
I don't really need the mesh to be dynamic and react. I'm trying to use simulation to give a more "leathery" feeling to the shape.

I've read that for closed meshes the best tool is soft body. Sadly I can't manage to use it properly, the mesh collapses almost instantly, whatever the parameters...

Here's the modeled cushion:

[image]

Here's where I struggle:

- Is the mesh too complex for the simulation to work properly?
- What simulation parameters can prevent the mesh from collapsing?

Comment: I think that the best way to achieve what you want is by sculpting or maybe even dynamic paint. Doing simulations or softbody would require to create some underlaying geometry to interact with the surface. A lot more complex in my opinion.

Comment: I actually have to underlying geometry (not shown here) made of a steel frame and leather straps. And I'm not that good at sculpting :)

Comment: Have you tried the "preserve volume" option?

Comment: I think that maybe a Displace modifier with a suitable texture might work? then you can just keep on editing the texture until you get it right.